# Find which points are unchanged under this reflection?

Tags: matrices

I am doing revision and I can't understand how to get the points here.
The Question is

The matrix $F =    \pmatrix{0& -1& 0& 10 \\ -1& 0& 0& 10& \\ 0& 0& 1& 0& \\ 0& 0& 0& 1&}$  represents a reflection; find which points are unchanged under this reflection ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

To find fixpoints of a tranformation, you need to find eigenvectors with eigenvalues $1$ of its matrix. Those eigenvectors span a subspace, in which all points are fixed under the transformation.

Comment: Let Ff=f. Then you find that f_3 and f_4 ate arbitrary but that f_1 and f_2 must satisfy f_1 + f_2 = 10f_4.

Comment: You are right, forgot to mention that.